# Matching Japanese regex (simple ranges) in bash doesn't work as intended

Tags: bash, regular-expression, language

I am pretty sure my regexes are fine but they don't work with bash. I crafted them myself using https://unicode.org/charts/. As you will see, they work properly with awk.

Here are the ranges to spare you the need to check them yourself, especially if you don't know Japanese:

- hiragana [ぁ-ゟ]

  - ぁあぃいぅうぇえぉおかがきぎくぐけげこごさざしじすずせぜそぞただちぢっつづてでとどなにぬねのはばぱひびぴふぶぷへべぺほぼぽまみむめもゃやゅゆょよらりるれろゎわゐゑをんゔゕゖ>゙>゚__ゝゞゟ
- katakana [゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮]

  - ゠ァアィイゥウェエォオカガキギクグケゲコゴサザシジスズセゼソゾタダチヂッツヅテデトドナニヌネノハバパヒビピフブプヘベペホボポマミムメモャヤュユョヨラリルレロヮワヰヱヲンヴヵヶヷヸヹヺ・ーヽヾヿ
  - ㇰㇱㇲㇳㇴㇵㇶㇷㇸㇹㇺㇻㇼㇽㇾㇿ
  - ！＂＃＄％＆＇（）＊＋，－．／０１２３４５６７８９：；＜＝＞？＠ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ［＼］＾＿｀ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚ｛｜｝～｟｠｡｢｣､･ｦｧｨｩｪｫｬｭｮｯｰｱｲｳｴｵｶｷｸｹｺｻｼｽｾｿﾀﾁﾂﾃﾄﾅﾆﾇﾈﾉﾊﾋﾌﾍﾎﾏﾐﾑﾒﾓﾔﾕﾖﾗﾘﾙﾚﾛﾜﾝﾞﾟﾡﾢﾣﾤﾥﾦﾧﾨﾩﾪﾫﾬﾭﾮﾯﾰﾱﾲﾳﾴﾵﾶﾷﾸﾹﾺﾻﾼﾽﾾￂￃￄￅￆￇￊￋￌￍￎￏￒￓￔￕￖￗￚￛￜ￠￡￢￣￤￥￦￨￩￪￫￬￭￮

I also have a regex to find kanjis `[一-龥]` but this one works as intended in bash.
The `>>> wrong!` are comments I added to pinpoint where the problems are.

```
[[ "する" =~ [ぁ-ゟ] ]] && echo 'is hiragana' || echo 'is not hiragana'
is hiragana

echo 'する' | awk '/[ぁ-ゟ]/ {print "is hiragana"}'
is hiragana

[[ "スル" =~ [ぁ-ゟ] ]] && echo 'is hiragana' || echo 'is not hiragana'
is hiragana >>> wrong!

echo 'スル' | awk '/[ぁ-ゟ]/ {print "is hiragana"}'

[[ "僕" =~ [ぁ-ゟ] ]] && echo 'is hiragana' || echo 'is not hiragana'
is not hiragana

echo '僕' | awk '/[ぁ-ゟ]/ {print "is hiragana"}'

[[ "する" =~ [゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮] ]] && echo 'is katakana' || echo 'is not katakana'
is katakana >>> wrong!

echo 'する' | awk '/[゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮]/ {print "is katakana"}'

[[ "スル" =~ [゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮] ]] && echo 'is katakana' || echo 'is not katakana'
is katakana

echo 'スル' | awk '/[゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮]/ {print "is katakana"}'
is katakana

[[ "僕" =~ [゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮] ]] && echo 'is katakana' || echo 'is not katakana'
is not katakana

echo '僕' | awk '/[゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮]/ {print "is katakana"}'
```

It's like bash consider hiragana and katakana to be equivalent, like it converts them beforehand or something?

Comment: I use Kitty, bash version is "5.2.2(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)", and LC_ALL is not set but the rest is utf8. I set LC_ALL as en_US.UTF-8 but it still is not working. As for your second message, you are telling me you have the opposite of my results??

Comment: Yeah, because my locale is set up in a strange way by default. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I guess that bash regex (POSIX regex) is simply not suitable for Unicode at all.

Comment: I'm getting significantly different results with `bash` version `5.2.15(3)-release (x86_64-pc-cygwin)` and `LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8`. Unfortunately as I don't know Japanese I can only re-run your tests. My results, with capitalisation for differences: `NOT / is / NOT / null / not / null / NOT / null / NOT / is / not / null`

Answer (score 0):

There is the script you want:

```
string1="する"
string2="スル"

if echo "$string1" | grep -P '[ぁ-ゟ]' >/dev/null; then
    echo 'is hiragana'
else
    echo 'is not hiragana'
fi

if echo "$string2" | grep -P '[ぁ-ゟ]' >/dev/null; then
    echo 'is hiragana'
else
    echo 'is not hiragana'
fi

if echo "$string1" | grep -P '[゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮]' >/dev/null; then
    echo 'is katakana'
else
    echo 'is not katakana'
fi

if echo "$string2" | grep -P '[゠-ヿㇰ-ㇿ！-￮]' >/dev/null; then
    echo 'is katakana'
else
    echo 'is not katakana'
fi
```

Comment: Use `grep -q` instead of `grep > /dev/null`

Comment: (1) So you're saying that it can't be done in pure bash?  If so, you should ***say so**.*  (2) And do you have a reference or source for saying that it *can't* be done in pure bash, or are you *just* offering a `grep` solution that works?  (3) Why do you believe that you need to use `-P`?  (4) Why are you not using here strings?  (5) `printf "%s"` would be better than`echo`.  (6) Rather than repeating code with different data, consider defining functions.

Comment: Also (7) consider using ``grep -q`` instead of redirecting output to `/dev/null`.